# Apps Script passing parameters to cUrl

Tags: javascript, curl, google-apps-script

I am pretty new to `Google Apps Script`. I am trying to create a script to pull data from a public API. I need to pass parameters, but can't figure out how to do it in `Apps Script`

The API documenation indicates that the information can be accessed like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 
--header "X-PW-AccessToken:<TOKEN>" \
--header "X-PW-Application:developer_api" \
--header "X-PW-UserEmail:<USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS>" \
-d '{"name":"My Lead","email":{"email":"mylead@gmail.test","category":"work"}}'
```

I have this function setup in `Apps Script`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://api.prosperworks.com/developer_api/v1/leads/search";
  var fetchParameters = {};
  fetchParameters.method = "post";
  fetchParameters.contentType = "application/json";
  fetchParameters.headers = {
       "X-PW-AccessToken": <TOKEN>,
       "X-PW-Application": "developer_api",
       "X-PW-UserEmail": <USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS>
  };
  fetchParameters.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  fetchParameters.payload = {"name":"My Lead","email":{"email":"mylead@gmail.test","category":"work"}};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchParameters);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

I added `fetchParameters.payload` because that appeared to be how to pass the values, but I get this error upon parsing the `JSON`:

```
Execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: <
```

If I comment out `fetchParameters.payload` it works successfully, but doesn't factor in any parameters (obviously).

I have tried: `fetchParameters.d`, `fetchParameters.data`, and many others, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation shows:

```
-X GET
```

You code uses:

```
fetchParameters.method = "post";
```

Try changing it to

```
fetchParameters.method = "get";
```